# Text position below mat card

Tags: css, angular, typescript

Experimenting with angular by building a site of mine and, I'm wondering how do I position text below the mat card while still keeping the mat card in the centre of the page (equal distance on either side vertically and horizontally)?

[here](https://stackblitz.com/github/crushdig/construction-webpage) is what the webpage looks like. The home-page-component is the part the question is focused on.

Comment: Remove `display: flex` from your `.home-Container` class?

Comment: I tried that before but it ruins the current dimensions of the mat card and moves the position of the card to the top of the page and not the centre of the page where it should be

Comment: You might need to draw up a picture here of exactly what you're trying to do

Comment: So, if i take out the text, the mat card is exactly in the centre of the page with equal distances on either side vertically and horizontally. What I want to test is the view when, I maintain the same layout while placing paragraphs below the mat-card, does this help?